# Wi-fi on Windows became very slow when I connect from Ubuntu

Tags: wireless

I have two machines in my Wi-Fi network: a Windows machine and Ubuntu machine.

When I connect my Ubuntu computer to my Wi-Fi network, the internet speed on Windows machine becomes awfully slow. At the same time the internet speed on Ubuntu is OK.
If I reboot my Ubuntu computer to Windows, all the computers in the network work fine.

I'm not running any p2p software at the time (Transmission is closed).
System monitor doesn't show any significant amount of network traffic on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no networking whiz, but I would see if this same issues occur with a different router or wireless network. Also verify that no unusual amounts of data or coming/going from either your windows or ubuntu computers. Obviously there is no inherent issue in Ubuntu that slows Windows computers on the same network, so without more specific details it's hard to give specific advice. After seeing this questions, you might want to investigate the specific wifi drivers that you're using: [Wi-fi interferes with other devices when connected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253470/wi-fi-interferes-with-other-devices-when-connected?rq=1)